# Centering text on a rectangle not working

Tags: c++, text, center, sfml

I have an `sf::RectangleShape inputFieldRect_` and an `sf::Text inputFieldText_` and I want to center the text on the rectangle because the sf::Text's dimensions will vary because its string will have different lengths.

After setting `inputFieldText_`'s string with `inputFieldText_.setString(s);` (`s` is a an `std::string` that the user inputs) I am adjusting its position so that it's still in the center of `inputFieldRect_`.

This is my code for that but the text is too much to the left and a little too much to the bottom, so not perfectly centered:

```
sf::FloatRect rectBounds = inputFieldRect_.getGlobalBounds();
sf::FloatRect textBounds = inputFieldText_.getGlobalBounds();

inputFieldText_.setPosition(
  rectBounds.left + (rectBounds.width / 2) - (textBounds.width / 2), 
  rectBounds.top + (rectBounds.height / 2) - (textBounds.height / 2)
);
```

Can someone please help me? I don't see the flaw.

Comment: Is there a thick border or padding inside the border?

Answer (score 1):

If the amount the text is out by is quite small, I suggest you look into where the drawing point for text is: it is usual for text to be drawn from the text baseline (Y) and from the logical initial X of the first character. Logical because that may be further right than you'd expect.**

If that doesn't help, it may be useful to investigate whether you should be using LocalBounds: sometimes in frameworks the difference is not as simple as it would appear.

** The difference is called the Left Bearing (and yes, there's Right Bearing too). See Remarks on this page: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrundrawing(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrundrawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)